# Getting a volume UUID in linux

Tags: c, linux, uuid

What is the easiest way to get the UUID of a hard drive partition programmically in Linux? (Using C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [libblkid](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/libblkid-docs/) from the [util-linux-ng distribution](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/).  It includes some [sample code](http://git.kernel.org/?p=utils/util-linux-ng/util-linux-ng.git;a=tree;f=libblkid/samples;hb=HEAD).

(Your system probably already has a "blkid" utility linked against some version of libblkid.)

Answer (score 2):

What Nemo said.

Or... You could open and read the contents of `/proc/mounts`, and ignore all lines that don't start with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`. Slightly more work, but no dependency.